# How can I resolve the IoT Hub error "A problem occurred loading devices."?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am using IoT Hub in Azure portal. If I select Devices in Device management, Azure portal displays "A problem occurred loading devices.". I guess our company's proxy server block the domain. We set the proxy server to through "portal.azure.com" and "azure-devices.net". But the error continue. What should we do? Are there any other domains that the proxy server should through?

Answer (score 0):

Are you still blocked? Were you able to access the devices earlier? Do you have the necessary permissions to access the devices? Please check the Access Control(IAM) tab to see your role assignments.

[image]

You can also add role assignments at Resource Group level. Go to your Resource Group, "Access Control (IAM)" and click on "Add role assignments". Then select "owner" and add yourself. See [Assign Azure roles using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current) for more details.

If you already have access and still facing the issue, then this could be a transient failure. I would suggest you wait for sometime and check back or clear your browser cookies, cache and history or try in-private mode and update if that solves your issue.
You can also log out and re-login to Azure Portal and see if there is any difference.